# Cannot convert to pdf from xlsx file over 1MB

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are using the following api for converting file to pdf in Microsoft Graph API.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/[item-id]/content?format=pdf

I tried to convert a .xlsx file that was over 1MB to .pdf by this api.
However, it returned following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "notSupported",
    "message": "...",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "OfficeConversion_NotSupported"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this behavior expected?

The reference for this api is below.

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a known limitation of PDF conversion for XLSX. I'd suggest making sure an idea exists, and is upvoted, on https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913708/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that it's better to add this limitation in graph api document.